# Getting 405 error - method not allow error in swagger while working in postman

Tags: rest, oauth, swagger, access-token

I 'm tring to run my API in swagger editor. But if I pass `oauth` token in header it gives me an error that 405 method is not allowed.

One more thing is it's working perfect in postman and terminal with `oauth` token. So maybe, the issue is with swagger.

Without `oauth` token it's working perfect in swagger editor.

> Without Passing oauth token in header my response is

```
Request URL:http://172.168.1.28/crowdfunding_api/public/v1.0.1/categories
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:172.168.1.28:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

> and curl url is when response is 200:

```
curl -X GET "http://172.168.1.28/crowdfunding_api/public/v1.0.1/categories" -H "accept: application/json"
```

> With oauth token in header my response is

```
Request URL:http://172.168.1.28/crowdfunding_api/public/v1.0.1/categories
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:172.168.1.28:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

> and curl url is when response is 405:

```
curl -X GET "http://172.168.1.28/crowdfunding_api/public/v1.0.1/categories" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: 587ded3104e6ba7535642e6fcc217e7aa0f5f087"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add support for `OPTIONS` method in your REST endpoint wrapper.
Just use something like:

```
if (method == 'OPTIONS') return;
```

I had similar 405 error and this helped me (seems that CORS sends OPTIONS first to check headers, whether request is allowed).

Also make sure, that your server returns headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "origin, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```